# Freeform 4.2.4 is, newly, returning no results, despite entries

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

We recently updated to FreeForm Pro 4.2.4 and EE 2.10.3 for a client. All forms were working properly before the update, now forms that submit seem to be working fine; but queries that display data results come back empty. For example, on the client's site there are multiple tools to view the submitted forms, but only if the user is logged in and has permission (I've tested with removing login and permission requirements, still no data).

```
{exp:freeform:entries form_id='4|5' search:list_optin='Yes' orderby='entry_date' sort='desc' status='open|closed' limit='100' paginate='bottom'}

        {freeform:field:email}, {freeform:field:first_name}, {freeform:field:last_name}, {freeform:entry_date format="%m/%d/%Y"}<br />

{/exp:freeform:entries}
```

The request is simple enough. It checks to see if submissions, opted-in for their newsletter (I also tested removing the field search and just returning any records using form_id=4). There are a few hundred records in the system that meet these requirements, and no results are being returned.

The form worked before the upgrade. It's not a new tool. But the only thing I can see wrong is that it indicates 'no GET data'. I'm just not certain why there's no GET data.

Comment: May be a silly question but you never know. What version of freeform did you upgrade from? Some versions require additional steps such as migrating entries.

Comment: I can't recall. I want to say 4.2.x, but it could have been a 4.1.x. It wasn't too long out of date. But I can go back and check the install instructions. It's possible.

Comment: If you go to the module and then click on the utilities tab it should tell you if you have any collections to migrate.

Comment: Looks like we are good. We were definitely in a 4.x situation, since each of our forms had specific database tables. I checked language changes and we seem to be fine with those. It's weird. The forms are working. But even the example tags for displaying entries don't work. Come to think of it, I'm having the same or a similar issue with Low Search. Maybe it's the EE 2.10.3 upgrade.

Comment: 2.11.1 is now out have you tried upgrading in case there are any known bugs causing the issue.